# Cannot open virtualenv on WIndows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual env on windows 7 - I have `Python27`, `virtualenv` in site-packages, Path set to `site=packages` and scripts, but am unable to open virtualenv.

```
C:\>python virtualenv flask
python: can't open file 'virtualenv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

With this command you are trying to run file `virtualenv` in folder `C:\`. It's not what you want.

I don't know how you've installed `virtualenv` into your Windows box but installation script should have placed `virtualenv.exe` in `C:/path/to/python/Scripts` (`C:/Python27/Scripts/virtualenv.exe` on my machine).

So all you need is to

```
C:\>C:/path/to/python/Scripts/virtualenv.exe flask
```

PS: It is a good idea to put `C:/path/to/python/Scripts` in `PATH`