# What's the structure of a valid Python SDK?

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

What is the minimal structure of files and directories required for a "valid" Python (2.7) SDK?

Why I'm asking:

I'm trying to import a virtualenv set up via Cygwin into the PyCharm IDE, file location `C:\cygwin64\home\MyUser\.virtualenvs\MyVirtualEnv\bin\python2.7`. PyCharm fails with message "Cannot set up a python SDK at C:\cygwin64\home\MyUser\.virtualenvs\MyVirtualEnv\bin\python2.7. The SDK seems invalid." However, I can successfully import the global Cygwin python interpreter located at `C:\cygwin64\bin\python2.7.exe`. Diff shows no binary difference between the files, so I assume PyCharm isn't finding an elusive something.

Comment: There's an issue logged for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13229

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot open virtualenv on WIndows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166602/cannot-open-virtualenv-on-windows)

Comment: have you solved that? I'm facing the same problem!

Comment: @AndreaRabbaglietti My solution was to stop using Windows for programming :(